# Job 'apply' button is not rendered when user agent is one word

Tags: support, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

I was looking on the jobs page and found that I never saw the 'apply' button.

I worked out that it was due to me messing with my browser's user agent during some tests earlier today. I found that the `apply` button only appears if the user agent string has at least one whitespace character in it: `a` does not work, but `a b` does.

When I encountered this problem, my user agent was set to `Mozilla/5.0` and I was using [Qutebrowser](https://qutebrowser.org) v 0.10.1, however I also tested with Firefox 52.0.2 (64-bit) which exhibited the same behaviour. I run Arch Linux 64 bit.

Comment: What browser / version are you using?

Comment: I use qutebrowser and originally blamed that! But then I fired up my Firefox which was the same. I've updated the Q with version details.

Comment: This might be some side-effect of blocking bots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't render the apply button to user agents that we've previously identified as bots. That cuts out a bunch of unnecessary traffic to the apply pages and is used as an initial way of filtering bots from our internal analytics presented to employers.

Right now that includes anything without a space in the user agent because 99% of the user agents we see have a space if they're legit user traffic. I've just tried Firefox 53.0 on OSX and Windows 10 and both have a default user agent with a space:

Windows: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0`

OSX: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0`

I don't have a Linux box to test on but I can't imagine Firefox special-casing Linux for this.

We're unlikely to change or remove the user-agent detection (even though we have more advanced bot detection techniques that supplement this) because it's a decent lightweight first line of defence so I'd suggest changing your user-agent; even [Arch Linux's docs for Qutebrowser](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Qutebrowser#Minimize_fingerprinting) suggest using a generic user-agent with a space in...

Comment: The typical user agent on Linux includes whitespace, for example: `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0` I only discovered this issue as a side-effect of myself testing something which required tinkering with the user agent (and I forgot to put it back afterwards!)